# How to find A%B for A and B are very large numbers (stored in string)

Tags: algorithm, modulus, modulo

If I have two numbers A and B and I want to compute A%B for A and B are very large (as large as 10^100), both are stored in strings, how can I achieve that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Comment: What language? Many languages (e.g., Java and Python) have ways of doing this for you.

Comment: `as large as 10^100` is that *value of the order of…* or *number of (decimal(?)) digits of the order of 10^100* (where base conversion alone gets, well, interesting)?

Answer (score 1):

10^100 is actually not that large, so you can just use a language like Python, which do not have an explicitly defined limit on the size of long integers.

If you want to just do the calculation once, you can just use a big number calculator like [here](https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work this out for fun, you can implement the division algorithm directly on the string representation.

Addition of two numbers is not a big deal (from right to left, add the ASCII values and deduct that of 0; carry if necessary). Subtraction is similar. And the comparison of two numbers is also very similar.

Multiplication of a number by a digit is also manageable (from right to left, convert ASCII->digit, perform the multiply and convert the rightmost digit to ASCII; carries can be larger but will fit in an int).

The key operation is: given a dividend and a divisor, find the leftmost digit of the quotient.

E.g.

```
3452 : 27
```

27 fits once in 34, hence the first digit is 1. Now subtract and get the next digit

```
 3452
-27
= 752
```

27 fits 2 times in 75, and

```
 752
-54
=212
```

Finally, 27 fits 7 times in 212 and

```
 212
-189
= 23
```

which is the remainder.

Comment: (: ASCII ;) or char or ISO-8859 or Unicorn or whatever magic is used to represent digits `in strings`.

Comment: @greybeard: EBCDIC is also possible.